# boot problem with linux and windows

Tags: boot

is their solve to my problem i was used kali and ubuntu and windows 8 but when am install new windows boot menu disappeared and my laptop log into windows automatically all time

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a live session, then execute `sudo fdisk -l`. I'm assuming that you will be shown that your internal hdd is `/dev/sda`. Otherwise replace `/dev/sda` with whatever your hdd is called.

Then execute these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```